# Provide password to bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, ubuntu

I have got a bash script, that encrypts different files.
This script prompts me to enter a password for each file(to encrypt).

Is there a way to give the information needed for the script as arguments to the script, so I don't have to enter them manually each time for each file?

I`ve tried:

- `cat "input" | ./Script.sh`
- `cat "input.txt" | ./Script.sh`
- `echo "input" | ./Script.sh`
- `printf 'word1\nword2\nword3\n' | ./script`

---

EDIT:
solved it with Volker Siegel`s answer:

1. Install expect: `sudo apt-get install expect`
2. Run autoexpect: `autoexpect -f file-to-save-automation script-to-automate`
3. Run genrated file: `./file-to-save-automation`

Comment: how is your script prompting for the password? and does it accept only one argument at a time for encryption, or does it loop over them?

Comment: this question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14392525/7552

Comment: @JeffSchaller It loops through the files and encrypts them one at the time. So currently I have to input something for every item manually.

Comment: @glennjackman Thx for the response, but I did not found something new :/

Comment: Close votes: please leave open, I made the title more clear, the question is pretty useful, the answer works.

Comment: simply run with `root` user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the program `expect`. What you need to do is the main use of it.
You use `autoexpect` to generate a recording of using your program.

The recording is a script in (tcl) that can run your script, including entering the password.

If it does not work perfectly, you can edit the generated script. The langue is no longer widely used, but pretty simple. Look at code examples for what you need.

You should easily find usage examples for your case.

Comment: Thx it worked using `autoexpect`

Comment: Yes, `autoexpect` is the name of the script generator - I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, arguments can be referenced with positional variables in your script.

EG -

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ge 1 ]
then
  echo First argument is $1
fi
```

Call it with `./my_script argument1` ...

So you have `$1` throu `$9` to use, adn if you need more than 9, you can use `shift` to, well.. shift them.

All of that said, accepting a password on a command line is typically bad, since it can be seen in hte user's history as well as in the output of `ps`, `top`, etc.  If it were me, I'd prompt the user for the password as part of the script.

Comment: but ... that's what they're doing already: `This script prompts me to enter a password for each file`

Comment: @ivanivan ok, I understand how it works. Now if I have a script that loops over each file and encrypts it(+ prompts for a user input) how can I integrate this?